# Windows mobile 6.5 IME

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, ime

Is that possible to send characters to currently open text box via IME ? What I am trying to do is that I have Bluetooth module that handles connection between Bluetooth keyboard and windows mobile device , when user press key on Bluetooth keyboard Bluetooth module receive it and send it to currently open text box via IME. You Comment will greatly help me as i am newbie in Windows Mobile development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the BT keyboard is using the HID protocol you do not need any additional software. All key strokes should be automatically routed as keyboard input to the right input.

If you need to write your own software, you need to open a COM port connection to the BT keyboard. Then your app can receive the BT keyboard messages and issues them as keyboard messages. See also http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2011/11/10/keywedge-updated/

But at all, your WM6.5 should have the HID drivers and so, after connection to the BT keyboard you do not have to do anything more.

Post the device model name, if you need more assistance.

regards

Josef

Comment: Thanks Josef , i tried to pair my mobile with Bluetooth keyboard , it starts pairing and take too much time then ended up with message "Failed to pair with keyboard Error occured". Do you have any idea about failure of pairing.

Comment: Hi, normally the WinMo 6.5 device should have a BT HID profile installed. But if not, the pairing will fail.
Which device you are testing?

See also [link](http://wmpoweruser.com/tag/bluetooth-keyboard/) for working devices.

If the driver is the problem, Teksoft offers an unlimitted trial of there BlueInput driver: [link](http://www.teksoftco.com/index.php?section=blueinput)

Comment: Hi Josef ,Thank you for your response. BT keyboard support SPP protocol not HID. It was taking time because it require insecure connection not secure connection. So via reflection I solved that problem.